# How to get the current logged in user in Bitbucket through JavaScript?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

How can I get the current logged in user in Bitbucket via JavaScript? Or is there any alternate way of finding logged in user in Bitbucket like we find it in Jira by (AJS.params.loggedInUser)?

Answer (score 0):

In old Stash (v3.6.x) terms this was:

```
require(['stash/api/util/state'], function(state) {
  console.log('Current user', state.getCurrentUser());
});
```

This gives an output of:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "active": true,
  "name": "david",
  "slug": "david",
  "displayName": "David Simpson",
  "avatarUrl": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/********.jpg?s=48&d=mm",
  "emailAddress": "david@dav1ds1mpson.me",
  "type": "NORMAL",
  "isAdmin": true
}
```

For a more updated BitBucket Server this would:

```
require(['bitbucket/util/state'], function(state) {
  console.log('Current user', state.getCurrentUser());
});
```